# How to stop Blazor from catching exceptions?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, blazor

I develop a server-side Blazor application in Visual Studio, my application uses Kestrel web server.
I can use a debugger, I TRY to use it at least.
When I set any breakpoint in any point of my code, the breakpoint is hit, Visual Studio debugger is shown, everything works like in any other NORMAL .NET application.

What I try to achieve is investigate / debug an exception that is thrown in my C# code in Blazor application. Exactly - it's a component code. I click a button in my app UI, an event handler is called, it starts executing code, I can insert a break point, so VS stops the program execution and shows me the line with the breakpoint, variable values and all. It's weird I'm even explaining it.

However, if an exception occurs in my program, Visual Studio debugger is NOT shown. The exception is intercepted in Blazor and show to the console instead. It makes debugging of the application super tedious and annoying chore. It also increases development time like 10x, to say at least.

I'm almost sure Blazor cannot be as stupidly designed and there must be an option allowing to debug it normally, using debugger that is already connected and working. Catching errors and logging them to the console or other log makes sense for deployed / released application. For development, especially in debug session in Visual Studio - the exceptions should be sent to the debugger. So there must be an option to enable such basic behavior, am I right?

I bet on appsettings.json file.

I spent several hours trying to find that information on Google and Microsoft Docs, but it seems either I'm the first person in the world asking that, or I just cannot figure out the right question or...

I'm really the first person in the world trying to use Visual Studio debugger to debug exceptions in my code. I mean in Blazor. Because I searched for "Debugging exceptions in Visual Studio" and it returns obvious (at least for me) results, like pictures of VS debugger showing exceptions. But if I only add "Blazor" to the question, the results are just crazy and totally unrelated.

Fun fact: when using `NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/Identity/Account/Login")` in my code, Visual Studio actually stops on exception, that is not really exception. I mean Blazor devs on GitHub say, the exception is a normal way how it operates. Feature not bug. So, when my application doing a normal, expected thing and works totally properly - Visual Studio debugger is suddenly shown and I see exception I don't care for. When my program performs invalid operation (a REAL exception occurs) - Visual Studio debugger does not show. The event is hidden and I either have to guess what has happened, or write some extra code to investigate. If that's not crazy I don't know what is.

BTW, I know there are workarounds for it. I'm not interested. I can use `Debug.Print`, I can insert a breakpoint and analyze the executed code step by step. I just want the debugger to be run as intended, automatically without hiding exceptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works as designed :) . Blazor, or any other asp.net framework has try/catch block somewhere in request handling flow. It's just to not terminate whole application if any exception is thrown. So exception is catched and you are not informed by debugger.

You can configure debugger to break when any exception is thrown. Look in [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/debugger/managing-exceptions-with-the-debugger?view=vs-2019).

Comment: I know how exceptions should work. The problem is - catching the exceptions where they SHOUD NOT be caught is insane. During development they should not be caught in Blazor or any part of the framework. Any framework COULD optionally (and probably should) catch its own exceptions, but not user's. I explicitly asked how to STOP Blazor from catching exceptions. I look for an option to disable that insane behavior. NET Framework or Entity Framework does not catch user code exceptions. This is not normal. Try / catch blocks are for programmer to use.

Comment: But OK, VS setting is a valid workaround. I just hardly ever needed to change the default setting in VS. Still, it's abuse on Blazor's behalf. It's similar code smell as instead of File.Exists() using try / catch block. So... accepted.